# Use EPPlus to open spreadsheet from server/LAN folder

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I'm trying to use the [EPPlus](https://epplus.codeplex.com/) plugin to open a spreadsheet on our LAN and having mixed results. In another program, an intranet website, the user can upload a spreadhsheet and the `ExcelPackage` object is able to open the worksheet based on the index.

However, now that I'm trying to open a spreadsheet based on a file path, as opposed to an [HttpRequest.InputStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.inputstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) I get he error

```
The given key was not present in the dictionary.
```

Instead of identifying the Worksheet I want to open via the index, I now need to specify it by name, which isn't the best option when dealing with multiple users like we are.

Does anyone know how, using EPPlus, to use an index to specify which worksheet they want to open when accessing and Excel spreadsheet from a LAN/server folder/location?

Here's my most recent attempt.

```
string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(_connString, "ZipCodeTest.xlsx");

FileStream stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

//EPPlus
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);
ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage();
package.Load(stream);
sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets["Query1"];
```

I'd like the final line to read like this:

```
sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

In EPPlus worksheet, you should start with *index 1* not 0 like this:

```
sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
```